# Retrieve all the articles that link to an article in Wikipedia but only if the link appears in a certain section of the article

Tags: php, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I’d like to retrieve all the articles that link to an article but only if the link appears in a certain section in the article that has the link. Usually, this “certain section” is the first paragraph of text. If we use first paragraph of text as an example, for the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph , I should retrieve the article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph'

Which has this text as its first paragraph:

> In mathematics, particularly graph theory, and computer science, a
>   directed acyclic graph (DAG /ˈdæɡ/ (About this soundlisten)), is a
>   finite *directed graph* with no directed cycles. That is, it consists
>   of finitely many vertices and edges (also called arcs), with each edge
>   directed from one vertex to another, such that there is no way to
>   start at any vertex v and follow a consistently-directed sequence of
>   edges that eventually loops back to v again. Equivalently, a DAG is a
>   directed graph that has a topological ordering, a sequence of the
>   vertices such that every edge is directed from earlier to later in the
>   sequence.

But not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)

Which has a link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph in later parts of the article (eg. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Directed_graph) but not in the first paragraph.

How can I do this? I do not mind using any method, and would prefer PHP as the programming language to use. More concerned about what platforms/APIs/tools wikipedia provides that can assist me in this endeavour eg. Which Wikipedia API entry point or methods would be useful in helping me retrieve links that only exist in some part of an article eg. The first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You say "articles that link to an article" but your question refers to the articles linked from an article. Can you clarify whether you want the links *to* or *from* [Directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph)? If you are interested in links *to* that article then you'll want an API version of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Directed_graph

To get the links in the first paragraph, you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&titles=Directed_graph&format=json&section=1

Change *section=1* if you want a different paragraph.

It will be more complicated if you are looking for all the links to a particular article (you will probably need to make separate calls for each).

Answer (score 0):

MediaWiki API offers an option to find all pages linking to an another:

https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Blinkshere

Unfortunately I don't think there is a parameter to specify a section number. But even if this parameter existed, page sections are numbered, and there is no "zero" section for the first paragraph of the page.